# Why my bind mounts don't actually bind some files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got some Python app which used bind mounts to mount code into container, so I don't have to build container on each code change, like this:

```
app:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./findface
        target: /app/findface
```

And it was working fine. But now I also want to bind my startup script, which is invoked from Dockerfile:

```
app:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./findface
        target: /app/findface
      - type: bind
        source: ./startup.sh
        target: /app
```

And this one just doesn't bind. There is an actual file in the host filesystem, but when I build the container it can't find it:

```
Step 7/8 : RUN chmod +x startup.sh
 ---> Running in ecaae384b6e5
chmod: cannot access 'startup.sh': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x startup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Dockerfile itself:

```
FROM jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv:latest

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir gunicorn[eventlet]

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x startup.sh

CMD "./startup.sh"
```

Comment: show the Dockerfile, the error is from the build stage.

Comment: you are missing the copy command, `copy startup.sh startup.sh` then run `RUN chmod +x startup.sh`

Comment: @Adiii but that's the idea, I don't want to copy it, I want to bind it into the container so I could change it's contents without rebuilding the container itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your comment, then you do not need set permission at build stage as the file is not exist at build time, if you do not want to copy at build stage, set permission on the host to make executable and then bind with docker run command or as per the yml config that you mentioned.

```
CMD "/app/startup.sh"
```

for example

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/startup.sh:/app/startup.sh my_image
```